# Stream content from external http resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to use my spring boot application as a proxy for certain image or video content hosted externally.

```
@GetMapping("/video.mp4")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getVideo(@PathVariable String filename) {
    HttpHeaders headers = getHttpHeaders(filename);
    ResponseEntity<Resource> exchange = restTemplate.exchange("https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(exchange.getBody());
}
```

I want to stream the content from the external resource to the client without downloading it first. My sample code above seems to first download the full content in to memory and then serves it.

How can I proxy the content directly without downloading it first?

Comment: Why use `restTemplate`? 1) It is a video file not a REST endpoint 2) it will by default "download" the video (because that is what it does). To stream it to the client, you need to stream if from the source first. Once you get that concurred,  you'll need to then create a streaming connection from the Browser client to your SB app - Good Luck.

Comment: If the source server does not send it as a streaming response then you will have to fully download it I guess. But once you have that file somewhere you could read it from file and return it as StreamingResponseBody.